# Where is the kafka bin to access the sh files in kafka docker container - confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Where is the kafka/bin location to access kafka shell scripts for the commands like

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list
```

This results in a blank response. I created topic from docker compose command attribute.

I tried searching,

```
/etc/kafka # This has only properties files
/opt/ # No subdirectories listed here
```

I am using the confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest image for spawning the docker image

```
kafka:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
ports:
  - 29092:29092
expose:
  - 29092
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

The docker container is running properly. I need to know :

- how to test manually from terminal within
- where is the kafka shell scripts

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would check under /usr/bin, but you do not need the absolute path. The scripts are already on the shell PATH.

> created topic from docker compose command

This would override the existing container entrypoint command which starts the broker, unless you mean `docker compose exec kafka "kafka-topics --create ..."`